# Is a text's max size include a null(stop) char

Tags: c, text, max-size

I want to define a macro which indicate the max size of a record's text.
like this:

```
#define RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE 255 /*the max size of the text which get from one record*/
```

Then use like this:

```
char text[RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE+1];
```

User must define array size "RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE+1" to include null char.

But I think I can define like this

```
 #define RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE 256 /*the max size of the text which get from one record*/
```

Then use like this:

```
char text[RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE];
```

I can not decide to use which.

Can you give me a suggest?

Which is the general specification?

Answer (score 3):

This is really a matter of preference, but my opinion is:

```
#define RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE   255

char text[RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE + 1];
```

The reason being that `RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE` still indicates how many actual *characters* can be in the buffer, while always leaving room for the null-terminator.

The problem, or counter-argument to this, is that most of the `strn...` functions (which take a length parameter) *include* the null terminator when limiting how many bytes to write.

Comment: I also recommend this style also other than use different words: `size` for `text` size with a value of 256 or use `maxlength` or `length` with the value of 255.

Comment: @chux, it is a good idea to use different word. Hope other person know it.

Answer (score -2):

As noted out by Jonathan Reinhart, this is really a matter of preference,he recommends this:

```
#define RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE   255

char text[RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE + 1];
```

which is a very good habit of course as will be more clear from my examples.

This is however, up to compiler to decide.The compiler automatically appends null character when it reaches the end of the text i.e. one doesn't need to bother about that.Whatever you put inside the "[]" of the array becomes the size of the text.Just take an example of the program which I wrote for this purpose:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define text_max 10
int main()
{
  char txt[text_max+1];
  printf("please enter the text :\n");
  fgets(txt,sizeof txt,stdin);
  for(int i=0;txt[i]!='\0';i++)
  printf("%c",txt[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

This program takes input a sequence of characters and the compiler automatically appends a '\0' after ten characters,but by declaring array size like this adding one more space doesn't confuse the person who reads the program or even yourself that where the last character went.You always know that you have to enter `text_max` characters.

INPUT: helloworldhi

OUTPUT:helloworld  //here "hi" is truncated and '\0' is entered after "d" and you don't need to think about the last character as you declared array size as text_max+1.

To clear my doubts I wrote another program like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define text_max 10
int main()
{
  char txt[text_max];
  printf("please enter the text :\n");
   fgets(txt,sizeof txt,stdin);
 for(int i=0;txt[i]!='\0';i++)
  printf("%c",txt[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

This program however printed out 9 characters,truncating some extra characters to accommodate the NULL terminator :

INPUT:helloworldhi

OUTPUT:helloworl   //here "dhi" is truncated and compiler enters '\0' after 9 characters.

which means no matter what you declare the compiler will always make room for '\0' character at the end of the text, but as you can see its a better habit to declare like this:

```
 #define RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE   255

    char text[RECORD_TEXT_MAX_SIZE + 1];
```

NOTE: compiler is gcc on windows.

Comment: For input larger then `sizeof(txt)-1` your examples run into Undefined Behaviour, as `scanf()` writes beyond the end of `txt`. `scanf()` (in the way you use it) has no idea how large `txt` is. Valgrind could prove this to you.

Comment: First of all `scanf()` doesn't write it reads,as for the use of `scanf()` I intentionally used it to show that no matter how large a text we input the compiler will append a '\0' after the limit of the text size (in case of larger text) and at the end of the text(in case of smaller text).I am totally shocked at the downvote. I didn't use a debugger but it worked perfectly fine for larger text,the compiler showed no error

Comment: 1st `scanf()` reads from a file and writes this to a memory location. 2nd: "*... no matter how large a text we input the compiler will append a '\0' after the limit of the text size ...*" This is plain wrong in the following way: If you pass 100 bytes to `scanf()` (as coded in your example) it reads 100 bytes, and writes 100 bytes to memory, even if the buffer provided is much smaller. And yes the 101st bytes will be a `'\0'`. However writing past the buffer's end provokes UB.

Comment: Then why doesn't the compiler show the error,If there is any UB it should exhibit right in executing the printf but instead it shows exactly the text of the buffer size.

Comment: Because this is C. The compiler assumes the programmer has taken care of passing a large enough buffer. To make `scanf()` stop reading into a buffer after a certain amount of characters do like this: `char txt[10 + 1]; scanf("%10s", txt)` to read in a max of 10 characters and make sure the compiler still has room to add the `'\0'`. UB **does not need** to make the program end, UB simply could lead to **anything happens**.

Comment: To test this run `valgrind ./your-test-app-as-by-your-answer` and enter let's say 500 characters and press enter.

Comment: "*... use strlen() function to get the length of the string it always shows number of characters+1 ...* this also is plain wrong. `strlen()` returns the number of characters up until the `0`-termination. If it does **not** the app already ran into UB, prior to the call to `streln()`, in the cases we are taling about most propably because of a buffer overrun by `scanf()`. Please see `man strlen()` for details.

Comment: @alk How about this - `for(int i=0;i<=text_max+1;i++)
  scanf("%s",&txt[i]);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32332/discussion-between-phifounder-and-alk)

Comment: Sry, I can not access the chat engine from here. Perhaps this evening ... in the meanwhile you might like to think about some test programs to prove the buffer overflow you are provoking ... ;-) Hint: declare `char txt1[16]; char txt2[16] = "0123456789ABCDE";` then overflow `txt1` using `scanf()` and printf out both `txt1` and `txt2`.